# How to measure total time when async function is involved

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function being called this way

```
do_work();
setTimeout(do_some_other_work);
do_work();
setTimeout(do_some_other_work);
do_work();
```

How do i output the total time spent in this case ?

Comment: please be more specific, what asynchronous function are you talking about?

Comment: Are those functions supposed to run sequentially? What second argument do you pass to `setTimeout`?

Comment: I don't pass any second argument to setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables: one with the starting time (to compare later), and one that gets incremented by `do_work()` and `do_some_other_work()` using a function that checks if the counter is at the desired number and then calculates the time difference.

So, something like:

```
var start = new Date(), call_counter = 0;
```

Then at the end of `do_work()` and `do_some_other_work()`:

```
incrementCounter();
```

And have:

```
function incrementCounter() {
    if ( ++call_counter == 5 ) {
        console.log( ((new Date()) - start) );
    }
}
```